# Wpf sizable element via conner

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I need in wpf have to elements 1 accros another and change his size.

[image: Like this]
[image]
[image]

I use this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Background="BurlyWood"></Label>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Plátno-->
        <Label Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></Label>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Black"
          ShowsPreview="True"
          Width="1" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Black"
          ShowsPreview="True"
          Height="1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It works, but only for vertical stroke and horizontal stroke. How can I add strok by conner for both together?